# Riddle -What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I got this riddle from a friend who told me that he invented it himself.

Please help me with this riddle!

*I am creamy, but I'm not cream.*

*I'm steamy, but I'm not steam.*

*I'm dreamy, but I'm not dream.*

Comment: Welcome to PSE. One rule here is to cite your sources when posting a puzzle that is not yours, to avoid plagiarism and to avoid unfair help in ongoing contests.

Comment: I flagged this puzzle for moderator intervention as the answer is offensive. Alexas, if you are aware of it, it's not very nice of you to do that. If you are not, and if you really want to know the answer, just google it (but another idea would be to go find another "friend").

Comment: While I don't find what the other commenters have found, I have a fair idea what sorts of things that might show up on search results for this combination of words. Without even needing to reach that, though, this riddle is very underspecified ... there isn't enough here to ensure there is a single definitive answer. Since any answers we might actually get on this would be equally uncertain, this falls under one of our close reasons ... for which I am closing it.